# Typescript Server Issue FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack, create-react-app

in my CRA project each single time I ran it I faced this error in my console. I think it is due to typescript server. Is there a way to solve it ?

```bash
99% done plugins webpack-hot-middlewarewebpack built preview 7c330f0bfd3e44c3a97b in 6446ms
Issues checking in progress...

<--- Last few GCs --->

[15997:0x7fccd3700000]   618460 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 2043.8 (2082.1) -> 2042.4 (2082.1) MB, 3304.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.202, current mu = 0.179) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[15997:0x7fccd3700000]   622127 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 2043.5 (2082.1) -> 2042.4 (2081.8) MB, 3661.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.106, current mu = 0.002) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x10e141815 node::Abort() (.cold.1) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: 0x10ce40aa9 node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: 0x10ce40c1f node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: 0x10cfc1877 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: 0x10cfc1813 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: 0x10d162c65 v8::internal::Heap::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: 0x10d166cad v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 8: 0x10d16358d v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 9: 0x10d160aad v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
10: 0x10d16dde0 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
11: 0x10d16de61 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
12: 0x10d13afb7 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/usr/local/bin/node]
13: 0x10d4f089e v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
14: 0x10d89a2b9 Builtins_CEntry_Return1_DontSaveFPRegs_ArgvOnStack_NoBuiltinExit [/usr/local/bin/node]
15: 0x10d82a983 Builtins_FastNewClosure [/usr/local/bin/node]
16: 0x119cedeb8 
RpcIpcMessagePortClosedError: Process 15997 exited [SIGABRT].
Issues checking service aborted - probably out of memory. Check the `memoryLimit` option in the ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin configuration.
If increasing the memory doesn't solve the issue, it's most probably a bug in the TypeScript or EsLint.
RpcIpcMessagePortClosedError: Process 15997 exited [SIGABRT].
Issues checking service aborted - probably out of memory. Check the `memoryLimit` option in the ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin configuration.
If increasing the memory doesn't solve the issue, it's most probably a bug in the TypeScript or EsLint.
webpack building...
99%
```

Comment: what node.js version are you using ?

Comment: @monim is use the`v16.13.1`

Answer (score 8):

This might be due to a leak of memory . just increasing the memory allocated to Node.js may solve the error .

In your terminal type this:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=2048"
```

if you are using windows run :

```
export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=2048"
```

Note : `size=2048` is the memory you will allocate in (MB) to node.js  the default is 512 MB

Comment: I still have the same issue

Comment: It works for me, on Mac, but with 5096 instead of 2048 (otherwise it fails).

Answer (score 1):

Update: if you get this issue while running unit tests with Jest, this could solve it.

I ran into the same issue today, here is how I solved it:

1. Add these line to your `jest.config.js`

```
coverageProvider: 'v8'
```

2. Add to your jest test coverage command

```
"jest -w 1"
```

If it is not working, consider upgrading your **node version**, to at least 16.10

Comment: What does Jest have to do with this error?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, on Ubuntu, but the value must be 5096  (otherwise it fails).